# Smeared creamy look effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

i came across a photo where the gradient looks like it s smeared from cream. It is hard to explained by saying so here is the [image: sample]
Let say i create 2 similar shapes with the gradient pattern then adjust the opacity but the edges will still remain. But in the example the edges are appeared to be soft and hard randomly. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a transparency gradient to blend the shapes.

(A) I duplicated a vector shape with some gradients and changed a bit the values of them.

(B) And added gradient transparency.

(C) The result

[image]

(D) But you can even add some gaussian blur to the shapes and again play with the transparency. This layer or object is above the previous one.

(E) The result

To this point, all "effects" are reversible (depending on the software you use)

One more thing is to actually do is take some blur or smear tool on your software and smear a bit.

---

Edit:

You can also use the mesh tool.

Here is a simple example, (done in Corel) but the idea is the same.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a solid walkthrough for me to try out. As far as it goes the trickiest  point to keep the edges off and on randomly. I really love this effect since i imagine it could apply to things such as snow dune, cloud, etc. Thank you